# MapKit annotation issue: can't create new spots on map

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I have a mapkit with a textField where the user can add his own spots; the program runs but when I type something and press enter, nothing happens, no new pin is set. Can someone tell me what am doing wrong? Code for Pin class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Pin : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *createdAt;
@property (nonatomic) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString*)name andCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;



+ (instancetype)spotWithName:(NSString*)name andCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;

- (NSString*)title;

@end
```

Pin.m:

```
#import "Pin.h"

@implementation Pin

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name andCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _name = name;
        _coordinate = coord;
        _createdAt = [NSDate date];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)spotWithName:(NSString *)name andCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord {
    return [[Pin alloc] initWithName:name andCoord:coord];
}

- (NSString *)title {
    return _name;
}

- (NSString *)subtitle {
    return [_createdAt description];
}

- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ [%@]", _name, _createdAt];
}
```

View Controller Implementation:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "Pin.h"


@interface ViewController ()<MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitude;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameInput;



@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
    _mapView.showsBuildings=YES;
    _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    [_locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation]; 

    _mapView.delegate = self;
    _locationManager.delegate=self;
}


- (IBAction)userLoc:(UIButton *)sender {
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(_mapView.userLocation.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake( 37.78583400, 122.40641700));

    [_mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];
}




#pragma mark - CCLocationManagerDelegate methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations {

    CLLocation *loc = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    _latitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g º", loc.coordinate.latitude];
}
#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate methods

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    _mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
}
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate methods
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)nameInput {
    Pin *pin = [Pin spotWithName:nameInput.text andCoord:_mapView.userLocation.coordinate];

    [_mapView addAnnotation:pin];

    nameInput.text = @"";
    [nameInput resignFirstResponder];

    return NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: You say "when I type something and press enter..." but then don't explain. I gather you have a text field in your app and the view controller is it's delegate, and the code in textFieldShouldReturn is the code that should be triggered and add an annotation to the map? Have you tried adding an NSLog statement to your code to make sure that method is being called? Have you stepped through your code to see what it's doing, check for nil objects, etc?

Comment: Yes, that method should add a pin point to the map, but in the simulator, when I type words, and press enter, the pin doesnt show up on the location like it was suposed to...I cant find the error, everything seems ok...

Comment: well, I think the method is not being called, I cant see the log like in others...but why its not being called?

Comment: What log? You don't show any log statements in that method. If you have not connected your view controller as the text field's delegate then delegate methods like `textFieldShouldReturn` won't get called.

Comment: Duncan C, the problem was this simple line missing: _nameInput.delegate=self;... - thanks for your patience anyhow :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, one line was missing:

```
_nameInput.delegate=self;
```

If I have a UITextfield protocol on the implementation, I have to assign it's delegate, in this case, it self, like the mapKit and the CCLocation Manager

Comment: Rules 1 of iOS development: If your code doesn't seem to be working when it should, check your outlet, IBAction, and delegate/dataSource connections. Rule 2: Repeat rule 1. Rule 3: See rule 2.